# Firebase Cloud Messaging on desktop

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, desktop

Recently, I have a task that relates to receive notification on desktop (Windows in particular). I've been researching several days but it's likely that FCM does not support desktop platform yet. Is it true and will it be available on desktop soon? Thank you all

I hope that Firebase Cloud Messaging support desktop platform

Comment: The volunteer community of Stack Overflow can't make comment about product roadmaps.  If you have a feature request, you should send it to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly.

Comment: *firebaser here* There are no current plans to add Firebase Cloud Messaging support for Windows or other desktop platforms. If you want to express interesting in such a feature, it's best to [contact Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) or file it on https://firebase.uservoice.com